# Where I can create pom.xml _ Android Studio?

Tags: maven, android-xml

I need to create `pom.xml` in my android studio project, where should this `xml` file be located?

[image: screenshot]

Which directory should it be in (`res`,`layout`,`xml`)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`Right click` on project and select `Show in Explorer` then copy `pom.xml` in project .

Answer (score -1):

Go to res > layout > xml  then right click the folder and select New > xml
Then type in "Pom.xml"